# How experimentalists make photons of specific frequency?

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, photons

I wonder how experimentalists make specific frequency of photon as they like?

Comment: Are you thinking of a specific experiment or wavelength? Do you really mean visible light only?

Comment: That all depends on what frequency and how many photons they need. The simplest is an arc lamp and a monochromator to get from the near IR to the near UV pretty easily. But, generally speaking, this is way to broad of a question.

Comment: This is a very broad topic. Probably the most common answer (by number of times it is done) is "buy a laser with the right pulse and intensity characteristics in a band you can make work". I mean, why screw around when there are such great sources available COTS?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way I have made photons:

1) start with a 4.0 GeV electron beam, c.f. SLAC.

2) place a thin copper foil (thin= 2%-6% of a radiation length):
This produces a blast of Bremsstrahlung from 0 to 4 GeV.

3) Observe the final state proton (at fixed angle) in $\gamma + d \rightarrow n + p$, which can have a momentum > 4 Gev/c, and you can look at reactions from just the high end of the brem spectrum.

This gets filed under "the hard way". But it works.

I have also seen people fire a laser into an oncoming positron beam (at 28.5 GeV). The Compton scattered laser light comes out as hard gammas in the lab frame.